# How to store/retrieve application data incase application deleted accidentally

Tags: iphone

I am having an application in which I am having SQlite database too ..If I delete that Application accidentally. Is there any way to get back the same application with the same database.

Or Is there any way to keep database alone in a separate place inside iPhone memory so that we can recover after application delete if needed.

Please tell me how to achieve the above?.

Regards,

V.K.

Answer (score 1):

Every iPhone app runs in a "Sandbox", which is where it stores its application files and databases.  When you delete the app, the whole sandbox is deleted, including your SQLlite database.  There is no way to write it outside of the sandbox short of having another app that listens on a URL and having the app in question write to that URL.